# id should be optional in angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

According to read me for angular-in-memory-web api 'The in-memory web api library currently assumes that every collection has a primary key called id'
Is there any option to have no id? as I would like to generate following response

```
{
    success: boolean;
    token: string;
}
```

Is it also possible to generate a string own its on, as my application returns a string when a post has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it's worse than this.

Not only must you have a Primary Key value in each of your tables called `id` but it must be a string, *not* a number.  (Huh ?!!)

If you don't do this, when when you try to call the PUT endpoint, the Angular code will throw an error on this line:

```
BackendService.prototype.put = function (_a) {
    . . . 
    if (id && id !== item.id) {
        return this.createErrorResponseOptions(url, STATUS.BAD_REQUEST, "Request for '" + collectionName + "' id does not match item.id");
    }
```

If your table contains a *numeric* `id` value, then this line will end comparing something like `"100"` with `100`, and will throw an error.

(Sigh.)

Answer (score 2):

'id' is must though you can ignore and can not use it.

But without id API will not work and will give an error.

> Collection 'your collection name' id type is non-numeric or unknown. Can only generate numeric ids